# How to group objects data inside an array based on a common parent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with dynamic objects (the number of objects will be a minimum of 1 to any). Basically, I have to group the data with parent and child elements. To be more specific, I have to consider the **School Name** as the parent and put the respective **Students' names with the ID** as the child.

**So here is the data I have now:**

```
eventArray = [{
  name: 'Inter school competition',
  totalStudents:25,
  school:[
    {
      studentName: 'John',
      studentId: 7,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'X High School',
        city: 'City-A'
      }
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Adam',
      studentId: 1,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'Y High School',
        city: 'City-B'
      }
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Jonathan',
      studentId: 2,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'Z High School',
        city: 'City-C'
      }
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Tann',
      studentId: 3,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'X High School',
        city: 'City-A'
      }
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Tonny',
      studentId: 4,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'X High School',
        city: 'City-A'
      }
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Azak',
      studentId: 5,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'Y High School',
        city: 'City-B'
      }
    },
    {
      studentName: 'Jonty',
      studentId: 6,
      school:{
        schoolName: 'Z High School',
        city: 'City-C'
      }
    }
    ]
}]
```

**This is the UI I have to make finally.** The parent and child list is dynamic (unlimited), so it will basically depend on the API.

[image: UI to make with grouping]

**How can I write this in JavaScript and use it in HTML?** Can anybody please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on school name/city.

Comment: Before the DOM rendering can take place the OP needs to restructure the given data. Thus, from what the OP provides as desired result the OP needs to group the student-data-items of following array ... `eventArray[0].school` ... by each item's `school.schoolName` value. How to group array data by same keys is one the frequently asked questions at SO. Maybe the OP already has done some own efforts on the data-transformation task and wants to share where the approach got stuck. Once people see that and how the OP tried there surely will be helping hands.

Comment: One question remains. Does the `eventArray` always contain just a single `'Inter school competition'` item? And if so, why provide it as such and not directly as e.g. `eventData` object-type?